# Twitter card title and discription not showing on large summary in tweets

Tags: twitter

My card title and discription only shows on the “summary” version and not on the “summary_large_image” version. I am currently using the “summary” version but the code is otherwise the same here is my code.

I want to display both title and description. If not, please let me know the reason